# Mathematical reason for scatter states being special?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

In infinite spectral theory, we have the discrete and continuous spectrum, which are called "bound" and "scatter states" in physics.

My understanding is, if $O \in B(H)$ is a self-adjoint bounded linear operator on the Hilbert space $H$, then the set of all eigenvalues $\lambda$ such that $O - \lambda I$ is non invertible, is the set of eigenvalues. If $O - \lambda I$ is not injective, then we get the set of discrete eigenvalues. If it is not surjective, but its closure is, then we get the continuous spectrum. In physics, the eigenvalues correspond to bound states, and the continuous spectrum corresponds to scatter states.

My reasoning for scatter states is that they are not in the Hilbert space of the system, but they are "special" in the sense that they are "almost" in $H$ - if we take $\psi \in H = l^2 (\mathbb{Z})$ as a scatter state, any truncation of $\psi$ will belong to $H$ as it will only have a finite number of elements, and so they are the closure of states in $H$. You can always choose a state in $H$ that approximates the truncation of this state $\psi$ to an arbitrary precision.

Is this logic and conclusion right? Why do we only consider the closure? What exactly breaks if we consider states that blow up to infinity?

Is there a physical reason for taking the closure? Tertiarily, I'm looking for a reason so as to why in physics $\psi = e^{ikx}$ type states are the only ones considered, and not states like $\psi = e^{lx}$.

Comment: Depending upon the problem, the states represent energy or probabilities. In Either case, you want them to be integrable, hence the restriction.

Comment: @PiyushGrover but scatter states are clearly not integrable, hence my question?

Comment: Isn't that why we work with a [rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) ? To include both bound states and scattering states. Unitarity of the evolution ensures that states of the form $\psi=e^{lx}$ do not appear.